# Как используя переменную %ProgramFiles% прописать путь до файла?

Tags: c#, .net

Первый код работает:

```
private const string _File = @"C:\Program Files\Folder\File.txt";
```

Второй код, вроде правильный, но не работает:

```
private const string _File = "\"%ProgramFiles%\\Folder\\File.txt\"";
```

Подскажите как поправить второй код, чтобы в системе x32 был путь:

`C:\Program Files\Folder\File.txt`

И в системе x64 такой же (без x86)

`C:\Program Files\Folder\File.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файловое API естественно ничего не знает о переменных окружения. Поэтому вам нужно получить их значение. Проще всего воспользоваться методом [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables(v=vs.110).aspx), который резолвит все переменные окружения в заданной строке:

```
private const string _File = "\"%ProgramFiles%\\Folder\\File.txt\"";

var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(_File);
```

Также есть метод [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx), который возвращает значение для указанной переменной.

Comment: Пришла идея, что путь не нужен вовсе, если создавать файл рядом с приложением: `@"File.txt"`

Comment: @Vitokhv вообще самая корректная реализация -- создавать файлы в директории пользователя, потому как доступа на запись ни к Program Files, ни к папке с приложением может не быть.